# Unity3D - Best way to load very high texture (84000x42000)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'm trying to use a high map definition from nasa (4x2 tiles of 21000x21000). So basically a total texture of 84000x42000.
To do so, I created a 4x2 shader, unfortunately with a 16k "max texture size" for each texture, the EXE generated is not usable (~9go -> crash when started).

- Would it work better to have a 8x4 shader of 8k tiles?
- Is it better to resize each tile to the max texture size ? ie: 16384 or 8192?

If you have any other idea to let me use this texture without losing too much quality, feel free to give my any advice!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the 3D model into several parts and putting 8192 texture in each part.